# NLTokenizer fails to enumerate words when text starts with Unicode "Other Symbol" followed directly by word

Tags: cocoa, nltokenizer

I'm trying to tokenize a string into words in a Cocoa app, but ran into a problem with `NLTokenizer`.

When the input string starts with a symbol from the Unicode category "Other Symbol" or the block "Specials", like the `NSTextAttachment.character`, tokenizing fails (i.e. returns empty list).

The problem only occurs when the symbol is followed directly by a word without a space (see examples below).

Use case:

I have an `NSAttributedString` that can contain images anywhere in the text. Those are represented internally by the Object Replacement Character (U+FFFC). When a document starts with an image followed directly by a word, not a space, tokenizing fails.

To reproduce:

```
/// Splits by natural language words.
static let tokenizeByWord:(String)-> [String] = { input in
    
    let tokenizer = NLTokenizer(unit: .word)
    tokenizer.string = input
    
    var tokens = [String]()
    
    tokenizer.enumerateTokens(in: input.startIndex..<input.endIndex) { tokenRange, _ in
        let token = input[tokenRange]
        tokens.append(String(token))
        return true
    }
    return tokens
}
//  These all fail: (string starts with symbol, followed by word)
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("\u{FFFC}hello world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("©hello world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("®hello world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("|hello world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("\\hello world"), ["hello", "world"])

// ✅ These all pass: (space after symbol)
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("\u{FFFC} hello world"), ["\u{FFFC}", "hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("© hello world"), ["©", "hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("® hello world"), ["®", "hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("| hello world"), ["|", "hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("\\ hello world"), ["\\", "hello", "world"])

// ✅ These all pass: (no space, but symbol rigth before second word)
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello \u{FFFC}world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello ©world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello ®world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello |world"), ["hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello \\world"), ["hello", "world"])

// ✅ Emoji pass with and without space:
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord("hello world" ), ["", "hello", "world"])
XCTAssertEqual(tokenizeByWord(" hello world"), ["", "hello", "world"])
```

System:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2)
- Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

Comment: What is `TokenizerStrategy` and what does `tokenize` do?

Comment: It is simply a function wrapper that takes a String and returns a list of tokens. I updated the source code to make it more clear.

Comment: I tried your code and `tokenizeByWord(" world")` returns `["", "world"]`.

Comment: You're right. Looks like I mixed up the sample code. Turns out emojis work fine, but it still fails for symbols in the Unicode "Other Symbols" category like this: `"©hello world"`. I updated the question, could you please take another look? The key seems to be that the string starts with the special symbol followed directly by a word, not a whitespace.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Try `" hello world"` and `"hello © world"`. Possible workaround: use `CFStringTokenizer` but avoid `CFStringTokenizerGoToTokenAtIndex`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll file a bug report.